# Looking at a specific timeframe for consecutive dates

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

This is a follow up question  [Check for 3 consecutive declined payment dates based on name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73392657/check-for-3-consecutive-declined-payment-dates-based-on-name) That I had the other day

The following is the same as the question above except, Jim has 2 loans to repay and the dates in df2 are not sorted in any particular order.

Jim and Bob are part of a loan repayment program. They need to be making monthly payments to pay off their loans. Sometimes, a payment can be declined for various reasons. I would like to find when there are 3 consecutive declined payments in a row(so no complete payment in-between any of the 3).

I believe the proper way to solve this is to look at a certain time frame. Having something that looks within a 3 month window prior to the due date seems like a good strategy.

Here are the dataframes:

```
DF1
| Name | ID   | Due Date               |
| -----| ---- |------------------------|
| Jim  | 1    |   2020-05-10           |
| Bob  | 2    |   2021-06-11           |
| Jim  | 3    |   2022-06-10           |

Here we have the "payment" dataframe.
DF2
| Name | Payment Date | Declined/Complete  |
| -----|------------  | -------------------|
| Jim  | 2020-04-5    | declined           |
| Jim  | 2020-03-9    | declined           |
| Jim  | 2020-05-6    | declined           |
| Bob  | 2021-04-11   | declined           |
| Bob  | 2021-03-20   | complete           |
| Bob  | 2021-05-11   | declined           |
| Jim  | 2022-04-3    | declined           |
| Jim  | 2022-03-5    | complete           |
| Jim  | 2022-05-15   | declined           |
```

Jim (ID = 1) has had 3 consecutive declined payments before his due date, he gets flagged(1).

Bob (ID = 2) had a complete payment in-between his last 3 payments, so he does not get flagged(0).

Jim (ID = 3) has a complete payment between two declines, so he does not get flagged(0).

```
Expected Output
| Name | ID |Due Date     | 3 consecutive declines    | 
| -----|----|-------------|---------------------------|
| Jim  |  1 |2020-05-10   |1                          |
| Bob  |  2 |2021-06-11   |0                          |
| Jim  |  3 |2022-06-10   |0                          |
```

I believe the proper way to solve this is to look at a certain time frame. Having something that looks within a 3 month window prior to the due date seems like a good strategy.

Comment: did the solution addressed your question?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

btw, we need an ID in the DF2 in order to map, otherwise, both JIMs will be treated as a single person

```
#map the due date into the df2 dataframe, so we can filter on payment prior to the due date
df2['DueDate'] = df2['ID'].map(df1.set_index(['ID'])['DueDate'])

#setup dates as dates
df2['PaymentDate']=pd.to_datetime(df2['PaymentDate'])
df2['DueDate']=pd.to_datetime(df2['DueDate'])

# get the count of declined payments for each ID
ref=df2[(df2['PaymentDate'] <= df2['DueDate']) &
   (df2['Declined_Complete'] == 'declined') 
  ].groupby(['ID'], as_index=False)[['ID','Declined_Complete']].size()
ref

#map the declined count to the DF1
df1['flag'] = df1['ID'].map(ref.set_index(['ID'])['size'])

# flag the customers that has missed the threshold number of payments, here its 3

missed_payment_count = 3
df1['flag'] = np.where(df1['flag'] >= missed_payment_count, 1, 0)
df1
```

```
    Name    ID  DueDate     flag
0   Jim     1   2020-05-10  1
1   Bob     2   2021-06-11  0
2   Jim     3   2022-06-10  0
```